# stupid bug with fscanf - comma instead of point

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have a stupid bug in one of my c++ source for a project. I do in this part of the source I/O operations. I have a stupid bug where I print the fscanf read value. Below in this part :
Firstly, I don't read the good value and when I print a float value, I get a decimal value with a comma ',' instead of a point '.' between the integer part and the floating part.

```
FILE* file3;
file3=fopen("test.dat","r");
float test1;
fscanf(file3," %f ",&test1);
printf("here %f\n",test1);
float test3 = 1.2345;
printf("here %f\n",test3);
fclose(file3);
```

where `test.dat` file contains "1.1234" and I get at the execution :

```
here 1,000000
here 1,234500
```

So, I did a simple test C program compiled with g++ :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* file3;
  float test3;
  file3=fopen("test.dat","r");
  fscanf(file3,"%f",&test3);
  printf("here %f\n",test3);
  fclose(file3);
}
```

and it gives :

```
here 1.123400
```

This is the first time I have a bug like this. Anyone could see what's wrong ?

Comment: *C program compiled with g++* is a C++ program.

Comment: This depends on locale setup. If your program must exhibit a particular behaviour (stuch as using `.` for decimal separator), you have to set the locale accordingly.

Comment: @nos: Nope, it's blatantly obvious. It's difference in locale initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your C++ locale somehow set to use a European convention? They use commas where we use points and points for thousand's separators.

Have a look at settings of environment variables

LANG
  LC_CTYPE
  LC_ALL

try setting en_GB or en_US. Having established that it is a locale problem, next decide what behaviour makes sense. Is diplaying 1224,45 a bug at all? The user has locale set for a reason.

Comment: One more important thing. It also depends on whether locales are initialized in the application. The test application does not initialize locales, so it's always using decimal point, the larger application probably initializes them.

Comment: The end user will insist on keeping their locale. This has to be fixed by properly enabling/disabling locale use in the application.

Comment: Thanks :  "std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "En_US");" in main.cpp dit it !

Comment: @user1773603 And probably broke everything else.  The (almost) first line in any console application written in C++ should be `std::locale::global( std::locale( "" ) );`; in C, this would be `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using code that using the locale set for the programs environment. In some locale's such as in French-speaking locale's, the comma is a the decimal separator. So this code is doing what its locale is presumably telling it to.

In your simple code, you have not initialise the locale support, so this does not happen.

Assuming a Unix-like environment, what is the value of the environment variable LANG, and the various LC_* environment variables?

> env | grep -e ^LANG -e ^LC_

For some background reading, try some of the GNU Libc manual (Locales and Internationalisation)

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html#Locales

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the application is setting the locale to the
users preference, with `std::locale::global( std::locale( "" )
)`.  Which is what console applications *should*
do, always; they should also imbue `std::cin`, `std::cout` and
`std::cerr` with this locale.  Most linguistic communities use
the comma for the decimal, rather than the point.  (For demon
processes, it is often more appropriate to use the `"C"` locale,
or the `"Posix"` locale under Unix, regardless of where the
server is actually running.  Since the `"C"` locale is the
default, doing nothing is generally fine for demons and
servers.)

The global locale affects *all* C style input and output, which
is yet another reason for using C++'s iostream instead.  With
`std::ifstream`, just imbue the stream with the locale in which
the file was written before doing your first input.  For 
machine generated files, the `"C"` locale is the usual default,
so your code would become something like:

```
std::ifstream file3( "test.dat" );
if ( ! file3.is_open() ) {
    //  error handling...
}
file3.imbue( std::locale( "C" ) );
float test1;
file3 >> test1;
//  ...
```

For output to the terminal, expect the locale conventions to be
followed.  And set the environment variables to specify the
locale you want to see.